# combining elements of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have three arrays in php script

```
$arr1=("a","b","c")  //(1,2,3)
$arr2=("d","e","f")  //(4,5,6)
$arr3=("g","h","i")  //(7,8,9)
```

note that, all the elements of three arrays are Strings. Also, there are same number of elements in all the three arrays.
i want output something like this..

> **$combined_arr("adg","beh","cfi")  //(147,258,369)**

how can i get a combined array like this in php..
can i add a character/string between each element of combined array like   "a and d and g"

Any idea? or guideline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you describe:

```
$final=array();
$count=count($arr1);
for($a=0;$a<$count;$a++){
    $final[]=$arr1[$a].' and '.$arr2[$a].' and '.$arr3[$a];
}
print_r($final);
```

Comment: @Tim a great approach, very simple and straightforward..nice...i am cursing myself why i wasnt able to do it my self..so nice of you ..+1 for you..and if you could, please keep me looking at my stupid questions...thanks..

Comment: i was sure before trying it that it is going to work, confirmed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try making use of [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$arrays = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];

foreach($arrays as $array)
{
    $chunks[] = array_chunk($array, 1);
}

$count = count($chunks);
for( $x=0; $x<$count; $x++ )
{
    $arr = array();
    for( $y=0; $y<count; $y++)
    {
        $arr[] = $chunks[$y][$x][0]; 
    }
    echo implode( ",", $arr);
}
```

With this approach, you can modify the number of arrays/elements in the arrays by just adding new arrays to `$arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$len = count($arr1);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $col = array($arr1[i], $arr2[i], $arr3[i]);
    // to join with ' and ' as a separator
    $result[] = implode(' and ', $col);
}
```